# Is a current git branch ahead or behind?

Tags: git

I am using a script (below) to modify my prompt to tell me the current branch and whether or not it matches its remote counterpart.  I am making an assumption based on the branch name as to whether a difference means the local copy is ahead or behind, but I was hoping there was a real way to determine that.  Note: git version 1.8.3.1 (RHEL7).

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>/dev/null
bname=$(git branch | awk '$1 == "*" {print $2}')
[ "${bname}" = "" ] && exit 0
rmtname=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} | sed 's/\// /') 
if [ "${rmtname}" != "@{u}" ] ; then
        rmthash=$(timeout 10 git ls-remote ${rmtname} | cut -f1)
        lclhash=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi
if [ "${rmthash}" = "" ] ; then
        status="[unknown]"
elif [ "${lclhash}" != "${rmthash}" ] ; then
        if [ "${bname}" = "develop" ] ; then
                status="[behind]"
        else
                status="[ahead]"
        fi
fi
echo " (${bname}${status})"
```

Example prompts (current, needs pull, needs push):

```
asw-dev:~/workingpool (develop) : 
asw-dev:~/workingpool/acropolis (develop[behind]) : 
asw-dev:~/workingpool/moira (im-123[ahead]) :
```

*(the part in parens is the output of this script)*

**Note: any solution needs to be suitable to be run after every single command entered (eg, it can't take 10 seconds to run)**

*PS, I looked at several Q&A's on SO, but they were either for a much newer version of git or not understandable for a git neewb like me.*

Comment: If it has to check the remote every time then network delays are probably your biggest problem. Can you be sure that they will be a negligible issue in your environment. Plus I think you mean the remote that is the designated upstream.

Comment: You can be ahead *and* behind at the same time. You need to account for this possibility.

Comment: Network delays are not in issue in my situation (.1ms ping, 1GB pipe).  I believe with our rules I can never be both ahead and behind).

Comment: Is `git rev-list --left-right --count branch1...branch2` sufficient?  This will list the ahead/behind count.

Comment: @alex I assume not literally "branch1" and "branch2" -- what does there?

Comment: Those are placeholders for the references to the local and remote branches.